# error with decimal in mvc3 - the value is not valid for field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, decimal, model-binding

I'm following [Getting started with ASP.NET MVC 3][1]. And I can't add/edit with value of Price = 9.99 or 9,99. It said: "The value '9.99' is not valid for Price." and "The field Price must be a number."

How to fix this?

**Model:**

```
    public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class MovieDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class MovieController : Controller
{
    private MovieDbContext db = new MovieDbContext();

    //
    // GET: /Movie/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var movie = from m in db.Movies
                     where m.ReleaseDate > new DateTime(1984, 6, 1)
                     select m;

        return View(movie.ToList()); 
    }

    //
    // GET: /Movie/Details/5

    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
        return View(movie);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Movie/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Movie/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Movies.Add(movie);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(movie);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Movie/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
        return View(movie);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Movie/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Movie movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(movie).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(movie);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Movie/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
        return View(movie);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Movie/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {            
        Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
        db.Movies.Remove(movie);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
}
```

**View:**

```
    @model MvcMovies.Models.Movie

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">       </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Movie</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Genre)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199835/mvc-3-jquery-validation-globalizing-of-number-decimal-field. It sounds like your validation issues are culture-specific.

Comment: What culture is the computer you are running the site on set to?  Does the culture use the decimal point, or the comma for decimals?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I just stumbled on this again after 2 years. I thought ASP.NET MVC 5 had solved this but looks like it's not the case. So here goes how to solve the problem...

Create a class called `DecimalModelBinder` like the following and add it to the root of your project for example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace YourNamespace
{   
    public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
                .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

            ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };

            object actualValue = null;

            if(valueResult.AttemptedValue != string.Empty)
            {
                try
                {
                    actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                }
                catch(FormatException e)
                {
                    modelState.Errors.Add(e);
                }
            }

            bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);

            return actualValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `Global.asax.cs,` make use of it in `Application_Start()` like this:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

Comment: Brilliant. Saved me so much time validating in JS if ppl put valid numeric characters in decimal input.

Comment: Remember guys, to bind non nullable decimals, just remove the ? from the decimal

Comment: I found this answer incredible helpful, thanks a lot, better than other solutions I tried before.

Comment: Client side validation is still an issue, when using jquery validation this will not help on client side validation bypass.

Comment: Didn't work for me. (It sent a new request so it was server side validation that failed)

Comment: I now use this modified version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9980369/5504438 and this works.

Comment: More than 6 years later and this still works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Note: do not forget to add also   "ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());" for not null fields

Comment: @maracuja-juice I had the same issue, but I'm not sure that the way you solved it is the best one. It made me feel that we are missing something... Aynway, thanks for that workaround !

Answer (score 7):

You are one of the non-English customers, which MS has not foreseen. You will need to put some extra effort into making your version run. I had a similar problem, denying me both "9,99" and "9.99" as valid numbers. It seems like once server-side validation failed, and once client-side validation, causing no number to be accepted.

So you have to make the validation congruent.

Like suggested in the comments, have a look at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674880(VS.98).aspx
and
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/10/globalizing-mvc-validation.aspx
and
[MVC 3 jQuery Validation/globalizing of number/decimal field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199835/mvc-3-jquery-validation-globalizing-of-number-decimal-field)
or - should you understand German (or just look at the code examples)
http://www.andreas-reiff.de/2012/06/probleme-mit-mvcmovies-beispiel-validierung-des-preises-mit-dezimalstellen-schlagt-fehl/

BTW, same problem exists for both the Music and Movie example tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this issue when developing a web application for an English audience, on a Pc in The Netherlands.

A model property of type double, generated this server-side validation error:

> The value '1.5' is not valid for .

On an breakpoint, I saw these values in the *Immediate Window*:

```
?System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

> {en-US}

```
?System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

> {nl-NL}

As a solution (or maybe a work-around), you can specify the globalization settings in the web.config file.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="en" uiCulture="en" />
```

Of course this means that you force your users to enter numbers in English formatting, but that is just fine, in my case.

Answer (score 4):

In 2019, this problem is still not solved. Using ASP Core 2.1, my UI is in French (decimal separator= ',') and I couldn't get the validation to work anytime I had a decimal number.

I found a workaround, not ideal though: I created a french-based CultureInfo but I changed the decimal separator to be the same as in Invariant Culture : '.'.

This made the trick, my decimal numbers are now displayed US style (but I am ok with it) and validation works.

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });


        //Culture specific problems
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

    }
```

Comment: You are a legend, still not solved in asp.net core 6!

Comment: For future reference... still not solved in asp.net core 7 (AFAIK)

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted the code from Leniel Macaferi a little bit so you can use it for any type:

```
public class RequestModelBinder<TBinding> : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };

        object actualValue = null;

        if (valueResult.AttemptedValue != string.Empty)
        {
            try
            {
                // values really should be invariant
                actualValue = Convert.ChangeType(valueResult.AttemptedValue, typeof(TBinding), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                modelState.Errors.Add(e);
            }
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);

        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried **@Leniel Macaferi** but it didn't work for me.

ModelState.IsValid didn't accept numbers formatted like 7.000,00

The problem started when I changed the property type from:

```
[Column("PRICE")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

to

```
[Column("PRICE")]
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

I've also tried to include the globalization on web.config that I had forgotten

```
<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
```

The only workaround that worked was change back the property to decimal only:

```
[Column("PRICE")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

and also changed the table column to NOT accept null values

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    var currentCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    currentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
    currentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
    currentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
    //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture;
}
```

To `Global.asax` (tested on MVC 5.1). It works without changing UICulture for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by disabled jquery for price and only validate on server side for that input. I found the answer here:
[ASP .NET MVC Disable Client Side Validation at Per-Field Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630424/asp-net-mvc-disable-client-side-validation-at-per-field-level)

```
<div class="col-md-10">
                @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DecimalValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DecimalValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of [Leniel Maccaferri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19339424/3762855) solution that avoids problems related to the sending by the user-agent of decimal values in a different culture format from the server one. Its limits are bound to the thousands separator parsing that, when it is the only separator in the value, can raise wrong bindings.

```
/// <summary>
/// custom decimal model binder
/// </summary>
/// <author>https://stackoverflow.com/users/114029/leniel-maccaferri</author>
/// <see cref="https://stackoverflow.com/a/19339424/3762855"/>
/// <remarks>Integrated with a fix for the decimal separator issue.
/// <para>This issue maybe depends from browsers interpretation of decimal values posted-back to the server when they receive response without any http content-language specific indication.</para>
/// <para>Important! decimal values caming from UI must not be formatted with thousands separator.</para>
/// </remarks>
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };

        object actualValue = null;

        if (valueResult.AttemptedValue != string.Empty)
        {
            try
            {
                var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

                //This is needed to convert in the right manner decimal values coming from UI, as seems they always represent the decimal separator as a period("."). 
                //Maybe depends from browsers interpretation of decimal values posted-back to the server when they receive response without any http content-language specific indication.
                if (culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator == "," && valueResult.AttemptedValue.LastIndexOf(".") > 0)
                {
                    culture = new CultureInfo("en"); 
                }
                else if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator == "." && valueResult.AttemptedValue.LastIndexOf(",") > 0)
                {
                    culture = new CultureInfo("it");
                }

                actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, culture);

            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                modelState.Errors.Add(e);
            }
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);

        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Just comment this link for the script:

```
<%--<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, this just _ignores_ it. The number format is invalid and that must be addressed.