# The value 'x' is not valid for latitute. (for Double Type)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, double, data-annotations

Variable in my model

```
[Display(Name = "Enlem")]
public double Latitute { get; set; }
```

part of my view

```
<div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Latitute)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Latitute)<br />
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Latitute)
</div>
```

And error:

[image]

with comma, Error:

[image]

How Can I fix it? I cant find what is the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822480/error-with-decimal-in-mvc3-the-value-is-not-valid-for-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the problem with client side validation and localization in jQuery.

[Short solution](https://mfranc.com/javascript/jquery-valdiator-modyfing-decimal-separator/)

Longer solution requires integration with [jQuery Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize)
This [article](http://www.campusmvp.net/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-coma-in-decimals/) describes how to alter jQuery number validators to perform the validation your way.

All those things apply to the comma problem, I don't really understand the second problem with the dot, so I can't help here. Try debugging what is going on under the hood and provide some more information on what is failing - client/server side and what is really happening.