# C# MVC Controller cannot get decimal or double values from Ajax POST request

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My problem is that when I try to send a double or decimal via ajax into my C# MVC Controller the value is always null. I can send the value as string and I can send Integers without a problem. Why can't I send values with decimals? When I check the request that is sent from the client the correct value is there (Form Data is `price=84.50`).

Error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'price'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Decimal'

Html:

```
 <input type="number" step="1" class="form-control" name="price" id="price">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.btn-success').click(function () {

    //var price = $('#price').val(); - Did not work
    //var price = Number($('#price').val()); Did not work
    var price = Number($('#price').val()).toFixed(2); // Does not work

    $.ajax({
        url: 'PriceFunction',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            price: price,
        }
    }).done(function () {

    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("Error in ajaxfunction!");
    });
});
```

C#:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void PriceFunction(decimal price)
    {
     // I have tried with decimal, double and double?.     
    }
```

Comment: you are missing a **.** after ``val()``

Comment: Sorry it was there in my original code, formated it to fit into Stackoverflow and I must have deleted it.

Comment: i could not reproduce this issue, "var price = $('#price').val();" just worked perfectly. the problem lives some where else. i can post screen shot as answer if u like.

Comment: Try changing the type from `decimal` to `string` just to check if it can't find the parameter or just can't convert it to a number.

Comment: You can better pass it as the string and Convert it to decimal  inside the method.

Comment: What do your routes look like in the MVC app?

Comment: What is the culture on the server? Is it one that accepts the `.` character as the decimal separator?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to stringify you data when you are sending decimal values.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ Price: 5.0 })
```

This is because the decimal is considered an integer by the default binder.

You could of course change to using the `DecimalModelBinder` which is detailed at the following link:

[ASP.NET MVC3 JSON decimal binding woes](http://digitalbush.com/2011/04/24/asp-net-mvc3-json-decimal-binding-woes/comment-page-1/#comment-3356)

Comment: This solution worked! In fact, the same strategy works for UIs in portuguese, where the decimal representation is different from the default in .net.

Comment: Check this out also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822480/error-with-decimal-in-mvc3-the-value-is-not-valid-for-field

Answer (score 13):

**This could be a Culture issue**

Be sure that the string you are sending to your action is compliant to the current Culture. (check the decimal number separators `.` `,`)

**Exemple**

e.g. on a french server, `99.1` will not be understood as `99,1`, but will be converted to `0`.

**Solution**

In that case, one solution is to define culture in your `Web.Config`

```
  <system.web>
    ...
    <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US"/>
  </system.web>
```

**Or**, replacing the separator by the proper one on the client side.

Comment: Exactly my problem!! Thanks, you saved me lots of time, would never have thought of that :)

Comment: That's solve my issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest trying to pass the data as JSON.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ price: price }),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Just pay attention to include the content type. It may be required in order to the binder know how to parse the data of your request.

Answer (score 1):

Try stringifying the JSON passed to the data parameter of the ajax call. That should do the trick.

```
var data = { price: price };

$.ajax({
    url: 'PriceFunction',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
}).
```

Answer (score 0):

First, using `toFixed` this way should get you an error since you are trying to use that method on jquery object

use
`parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is working in fact but
the solution I use  it is.
You have to send  value as a string and convert it into decimal on server side.

**So your JS is perfect!**

```
$('.btn-success').click(function () {

    //var price = $('#price').val(); - Did not work
    //var price = Number($('#price').val()); Did not work
    var price = Number($('#price').val()).toFixed(2); // Does not work

    $.ajax({
        url: 'PriceFunction',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            price: price,
        }
    }).done(function () {

    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("Error in ajaxfunction!");
    });
});
```

**C#**

```
public readonly CultureInfo ciEN = new CultureInfo("en-US");
 
public async Task<ActionResult> YourMVCMethod(string myDecimalValue)
{
   var message = string.Empty;
   bool result = false;

   try
   {
         decimal convertedValue = Convert.ToDecimal(myDecimalValue, ciEN);
         // process it...                   
                
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       return Json(new { success = result, msg = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }

   return Json(new { success = result, msg = message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Web.Config

It contains your global culture!

```
<globalization uiCulture="your" culture="your-CULTURE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to force decimal parsing at the backend side for "en-US" culture is to set it somewhere in the startup of the application (if you don't want to do it through *web.config*).

For ASP.NET MVC it may be e.g. *Global.asax*, whie for ASP.NET Core MVC it may be *Startup.cs*.

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = ci;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = ci;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
var price = Number($('#price').val().toFixed(2));
```

To

```
var price = parseFloat($('#price').val()).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:

```
    public class test
    {
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Test(test whatever)
    {
        // I have tried with decimal, double and double?.     
    }
```

Care about property Name and dataType: 'json' in Ajax call

Answer (score -1):

For me only this way works:

```
type: "POST",
data: 'price': parseFloat($(#price).val()).toFixed(2).replace(".", ","),
success: function(data){
...
}
```

It probably depend from your current culture in environment.
I hope it will helps someone.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22291462)

Answer (score -1):

I had to bind more complex model, so stringify solution was not what I wanted.
So i found this article which shows how to extend default model binder to accept decimals.

Here is the code from [haacked.com](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/):

First you extend IModelBinder:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, 
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e) {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

Then you register this binder:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());

    // All other stuff ...
}
```