# How do I pass decimal values to controller using Ajax?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, binding, decimal

I have a number input, and when the user enters a number, it will be sent from the view to the controller using Ajax. Everything works fine, but when the user enters decimal numbers, I get binding errors (1,1 or 1.2 etc). I want the user to be able to use decimal numbers.

This is the relevant View code:

```
var postdata = {x: <number input value>};
$.ajax({url: url, type: "POST", data: postdata, async: false})
```

This is the Controller function:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyFunction(decimal x) 
{
  return Json(new {success = true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet});
}
```

Comment: Try `{x: 1.1};`

Comment: Just did a small edit on my post. Problem is when the data is taken directly out of the input field: $("#input").val()

Comment: `parseFloat($("#input").val() `

Comment: If so, try to trim the value before placing it inside the object

Comment: I didn't have any luck with parseFloat. What do you mean with "trim"? In what way?

Comment: It seems there is the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908503/c-sharp-mvc-controller-cannot-get-decimal-or-double-values-from-ajax-post-reques)

Comment: @Pelle what error you are getting ?

Comment: I tried JSON.stringify. Didn't have any luck with that either when data was taken directly out of input.

Comment: This is the error: "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'x' of non-nullable type 'System.Decimal' for method [...]"

Comment: try: var postdata = { "x" : 1.2 };  $.ajax({url: url, type: "POST", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json", data: postdata, async: false})

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to make it work with the solutions provided in this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908503/c-sharp-mvc-controller-cannot-get-decimal-or-double-values-from-ajax-post-reques) before posting your question? Your question seems a lot more duplicate.

Comment: Yes. I stated that in the answer below, and other people suggested JSON.stringify here as well, which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify you data when you are sending decimal values.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ x: 5.0 })
```

This is because the decimal is considered an integer by the default binder.

Please have a look on lelow link for more information :-

[C# MVC Controller cannot get decimal or double values from Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908503/c-sharp-mvc-controller-cannot-get-decimal-or-double-values-from-ajax-post-reques)

**Edit 1:-**

You can also try :-

```
parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: I have tried that. Same error. Edit: toFixed(2) didn't work any better.

Answer (score 0):

just send the value as it is and try to convert in controller instead

```
 var postdata = {x: $("#input").val()};
    $.ajax({url: url, type: "POST", data: postdata, async: false})
```

This is the Controller function:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyFunction(string x) 
{
 double z=Convert.ToDouble(x.Trim()); // trim just in case....


  return Json(new {success = true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet});
}
```

In case of your  double   try this it should work (replacing . with ,)

```
double.Parse("52.8725945", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I am not able to use var as a parameter type. As far as I know, the compiler won't be able to deduce the type. Atleast I get an error.

Comment: i have tried with double.Parse() it working you just need to replace "," with "."

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, with a double (not a decimal), but I think the solution might be the same.
For me it was all about culture and setting the right number format!

**Solution:**

```
NumberFormat = NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;
```

This is a parameter of the `CultureInfo` of the app! You can set this in multiple places. If there is only one culture on your app, set this on `Application_Start()` on `Global.asax`.

No changes on Web.config and works with `$("#input").val()` (with or without `parseFloat()`).

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple:

Model:

```
public decimalValue
```

In Ajax data:

```
$("#value").val().replace(",",".")
```

It will automatically send the value to the Controller.

```
(10.90, 10.90)
```

Declaring the `Input` as a number helps not to give an error, if you send a string.