# parseFloat() does not work with the value I get from number type input

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, parsefloat

When I made the value of input in type number parseFloat() and sent it to ajax post and controller, the conversion didn't occur. For example: `parseFloat("1.56")` returns `156`.

```
  Data: function (show, type) {
        var whattoreturn = new FormData();
        whattoreturn.append("ProductDiameter",parseFloat($('#csdiameter').val()));
        return whattoreturn;
    }
var ajax = {
                url: "/Product/SaveProduct/",
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: Product.Data(show),
                success: function (data) {}
                }
```

```csharp
public decimal ProductDiameter { get; set; }
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control m-input" id="csdiameter" value="" >
```

Comment: Are you saying that the value is `156` when viewed in your JS or C# code? In either case I'm unable reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/d4s3zxym/

Comment: Can you also share your ajax post code?

Comment: It does so when it comes to controller.When I write parseFloat() to console(F12), it works correctly.

Comment: In which case something is happening to the value between you retrieving it and sending it in the AJAX request. Could you please add that code to the question

Comment: I also added ajax code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# MVC Controller cannot get decimal or double values from Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908503/c-sharp-mvc-controller-cannot-get-decimal-or-double-values-from-ajax-post-reques)

Comment: still not happening