# System.InvalidOperationException inside HtmlHelper MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have my `CreateGame` View with three elements in a row: a `label`, a `dropdownlist` and an `editbox` to put a decimal number.

It goes like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-1.5">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.id1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.id1, (SelectList)ViewBag.Lista, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.rating_1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.rating_1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically I want to identify which player (from the dropdownlist) played the game and to assign him a certain rating.

Now I have two different scenarios. I can either put an integer number for the rating and everything runs smoothly or I can put a decimal number (that's the point) and a `System.InvalidOperationException` exception is thrown in this line:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.id1, (SelectList)ViewBag.Lista, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

stating

> The ViewData item that has the key 'id1' is of type 'System.Int32' but
>   must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

I know what the error message is saying, but I don't understand how can the `rating` property changes the way the compiler looks at a line above. How can I be able to insert a decimal number for the rating?

**EDIT:**

Btw, this is how I create my `ViewBag.Lista` on my controller:

```
 var lista = db.Players
      .Select(p => new SelectListItem
      {
          Text = p.name,
          Value = p.ID.ToString()
      }).ToList();

  ViewBag.Lista = new SelectList(lista, "Value", "Text");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in your model where you have `id1` set:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Your_name_list {get; set;}
```

And in the view set this list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.id1, model.Your_name_list, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: That solved only half my problem, but I'll mark it as the answer as it was usefull for me. I still can't manage to validate decimal numbers for my "rating" property. Is there any validation annotation I'm missing?

Comment: For example in jQuery you can write regexp and you can try validate decimal number for your "rating" property.

Comment: I tried the solution provided by Dave_cz in the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822480/error-with-decimal-in-mvc3-the-value-is-not-valid-for-field And it's working great so far.