# Asp.Net Form Input With Comma

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form with an input that collects a dollar amount (ex: `$5,000`)

How can I allow an input of `$5,000` to not trigger `(!ModelState.IsValid)` remove comma (`,`) and `$` for POSTing?

ViewModel

```
public class FormViewModel
{
    [Required, RegularExpression("[0-9,]")]
    public int? Amount { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<form>
  <input asp-for="Amount" />
  <span asp-validation-for="Amount"></span>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostForm(FormViewModel viewModel)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(viewModel)
  }
  else
  {
  //Post Form
  }
}
```

Comment: You can make HTML helper method to extract whatever you want from the input based on this criteria

Comment: Use `[DataType(DataType.Currency)]` attribute on the property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using AutoMapper to map the the properties back and forth.

I changed my ViewModel to a String and then used automapper like below:

```
//Map From Int To String
CreateMap<Models.ServiceModel, FormViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.Amount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Amount.ToString()));


//Map From String Back To Int
CreateMap<FormViewModel, Models.ServiceModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.Amount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => int.Parse(src.Amount.Replace(",", ""))));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the View Model to accept a string instead of `int?` for the `Amount` property:

```
public class FormViewModel {
    public string Amount { get; set; }

    public int? Value {
        get {
            int result = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(Amount, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, result) {
                return result;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now user input is stored in the `Amount` property, while parsed integer value is stored in `Value` property.

Comment: This works but how would I reverse this? So I am able to POST but how would I then GET that value and put back into the form?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the IModelBinder?

```
public class DecimalModelBinder: System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        if (valueResult.AttemptedValue != string.Empty)
        {
            try
            {
                string attemptedVal = valueResult.AttemptedValue?.Replace(",", ".").Replace("$", "");
                actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(attemptedVal, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                modelState.Errors.Add(e);
            }
        }
        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

Itsnot the same but a similar answer to: [error with decimal in mvc3 - the value is not valid for field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822480/error-with-decimal-in-mvc3-the-value-is-not-valid-for-field)

Answer (score 0):

Update the model to use data type annotations.

```
public class FormViewModel {
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Required]
    public int? Amount { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to include cents then change property to decimal

```
public class FormViewModel {
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Required]
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
}
```