# Decimal value not accepted with "," and "."

Tags: asp.net

My Model (Generated from db sql server):

```
public partial class Wagons
{
public int ID {get; set;}
public decimal Poids {get; set;}

 }
```

And with Entity Framework I generated my Controller and View.

When I tried to enter the data I got something like this:[image]

and my propriety is Decimal, I replaced "," by "." I got an other error : The value is not valid for...
[image]
How can I fix this please? 
Regards

Comment: We need to see your code, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: it would be easier to help if you add what validation the textbox is using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error with decimal in mvc3 - the value is not valid for field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822480/error-with-decimal-in-mvc3-the-value-is-not-valid-for-field)

Comment: Read [ask] and share your research.

Comment: I updated my Question, please see it again.

Comment: Your error message (and field label) shows a "Threshold Price". Your code doesn't mention that, but a "Poids". Please show the code that belongs to the field shown (or how Poids is linked to that field)

Comment: @Hans sorry I coudn't change the message (), the error message is : "The field Poids must be a number".

Answer (score 0):

AspNet tries to parse string to decimals based on the active Culture info

In USA the decimal separator is a dot (.)

in for example The netherlands this is a comma  (,)

and thus depending on the culture settings some formats can and some formats can't be parsed to decimals

read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-numeric

Comment: @CodeCaster you don't know it could be after a post or ajax call. since the tag is aspnet i answer the aspnet way.