# The decimal field must be a number in .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core

I have the known problem on decimal data types and the error "The field fieldname must be a number." I'm developing a ASP.NET Web App in .NET Core 2.2 with c#.

The model extract is the following:

```
    public DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; }
    public decimal? TimeZone { get; set; }
    public int? Idwfstate { get; set; }
```

and the cshtml extract is as follows:

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="item.TimeZone" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="item.TimeZone" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="item.TimeZone" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

After enabling globalization for jquery validation plugin and putting the following code in startup.cs :

```
        var defaultCulture = new CultureInfo("us-UK");
        var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultCulture),
            SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { defaultCulture },
            SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { defaultCulture }
        };
        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

the problem persist.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What known problem? Where did this error come from? Compilation? Runtime? Javascript? Are you sure it's not caused by invalid input, or a globalization issue?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822480/error-with-decimal-in-mvc3-the-value-is-not-valid-for-field/37135252#37135252

Comment: So you know this is a *globalization issue*, the input is invalid and you need to specify the correct culture, not disable validation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : So I have to fix a culure with a specified decimal point for rhe application.

Comment: ASP.NET Core uses the [jQuery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). You need to enable globalization for the . This is shown  [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/4076#issuecomment-326590420) and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1212247/jQuery-culture-validation-in-ASP-NET-Core).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos :  Hi, I did everything you suggested, but the problem persists. What can it be?

Comment: What you want is to  make the validation message appear as the language of the corresponding culture ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to localize ASP.NET Core Model Binding Error Messages ,follow these steps :

1. **Create Resource File** - Create a resource file under `Resources` folder
   in your solution and name the file `ModelBindingMessages.fa.resx`.
2. **Add Resource Keys** - Open the resource file and add keys and values
   which you want to use for localizing error messages. I used keys and
   values like below image:
   [image]
3. **Configure Options** - In `ConfigureServices` method, when adding `Mvc`, configure its options to set message accessors for `ModelBindingMessageProvider`:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddLocalization(options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources";});

       services.AddMvc(options =>
       {
           var F = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IStringLocalizerFactory>();
           var L = F.Create("ModelBindingMessages", "RazorPages2_2Test");
           options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueIsInvalidAccessor(
               (x) => L["The value '{0}' is invalid."]);
           options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustBeANumberAccessor (
               (x) => L["The field {0} must be a number."]);

       } )
           .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
           .AddViewLocalization()
           .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
   ```

   The current culture on a request is set in the localization Middleware. The localization middleware is enabled in the `Startup.Configure` method. The localization middleware must be configured before any middleware which might check the request culture (for example, `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()`).

   ```
      var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("fa") };
       app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions()
       {
           DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(new CultureInfo("en")),
           SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
           SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
       });
   ```

Reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41669552/10201850