# ViewModel decimal being converted to thousands with French comma

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internationalization

I have the following MVC ViewModel:

```
public class Payment
{
    [Required]
    [Range(5, 1000)]
    public decimal RebillAmount { get; set; }
}
```

When I have switched the application language to French Canadian using:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fr-CA");

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

Then submit a decimal with `300,00` in the input field, the value for the decimal is converted to `30000` when retrieving the value in my controller?

For example:

```
public ActionResult Save(Payment model)
{
    decimal amount = model.RebillAmount; // <- Returns 30000, not 300.00
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The culture is set manually for testing (as shown above), but it's actually configurable by each user using a session variable.

Comment: Set the culture of your app in the web.config file.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can't do that because the language must be configurable by the user. The above was hard-coded for testing.

Comment: Perhaps you should have stated that in your question :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke you're right, that's my bad! Apologies, I'll update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to write a Custom Model Binder to do this.

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue,
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

In your Global.asax file, add the following to your Application_Start Method

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Though it's still being returned as 30000 when inputting 300,00, but I've uncovered a part of the issue. It seems the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is being set **after** this model binder runs. The language is being switched inside the controller method `OnActionExecuting`, where should I switch the language so it persists *before* this model binder runs?

Comment: Maybe in an `ActionFilterAttribute`?

Comment: @SteveBauman check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980104/mvc-3-client-side-validation-model-binding-decimal-value-and-culture-different?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with latitude and longitude data, the commas dissapeared due to client formats, I solved doing this:

**Startup configuration**

```
        IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        };

        IList<CultureInfo> supportedCulturesUI = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("es-EC"),
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCulturesUI
        });
```

**POCO Class**

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 6)")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.000000}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public virtual decimal baLatitude { get; set; }
```

**The latitude and longitude data were captured by the google maps api and written in hidden controls in the view**

```
<div class="is-hidden">
    <input asp-for="baLatitude">
</div>
```